# Sum rows of one dataset meeting the criteria of another dataset in R

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I need help coding the following: I would like to randomly sample values from the FIRST column of “s” and add these values until their sum equal the first, second, etc. rows of the FIRST column of “dat”, randomly sample values from the SECOND column of ”s” and add these values until their sum equal the first, second, etc. rows of SECOND column of “dat”, repeating this process for all 6 columns. The final output should match the structure of dat and contain the count of rows from "s" meeting the criteria of each cell in "dat".

This is an approximation of what I want- through the code is only for a single cell of the FIRST column of “dat” and a the corresponding FIRST column of “s” since I am having trouble indexing “s” and “dat”.

```
set.seed(1234)
dat<-matrix(rnorm(30, 50, 10), ncol=5)
dat<-as.data.frame(round(dat))
dat.V1<-dat[,1]
s<-matrix(rnorm(60, 7, 2), ncol=5)
s<-as.data.frame(s)
s.V1<-s[,1]

total  <- 0
result <- 0
  while (result<= dat.V1[1]) {
    result_ind = sum(result + s.V1[sample(s.V1, 1)])- result
    result     = result + s.V1[sample(s.V1, 1)]
    total      = total + 1 
    if(result == dat.V1[1]) break
  }

allout<-cbind(dat.V1[1], result, total)
allout
      result total
[1,] 38 41.47509     7
```

Here dat.V1[1]= 38, the sum of random values from s.V1=41.47509 (I wanted a value s.V1≈ dat.V1[1], but close enough), with the count of s.V1 =7 meeting the criteria for this cell. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please do add the `set.seed(1234)` to your code. With random number generation it is  a best practice to add that piece of code in order to make number reproducible.

Comment: i'm quite confused what your condition means. e.g. the probability of the sums being equal is 0.

Comment: what if the `cumsum` is never >= one of your threshold values?

Comment: Also, I think you're making this more complicated than you need to. You have a vector of values (say `v1`) for which you wish to compare cumulative sums to a vector of threshold values (say `v2`). The return is the length of `v1` (n) s.t. `cumsum(v1[1:n]) >= v2[j]` ... one you can do that for two vectors, the extension to matrices / data.frames should be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that produces a matrix of values that are the min(index of S_i)
that has cumsum(S_i) >= threshold value V_n,m. 0 means that V_n,m > cumsum(S_i). I have modified the solution to randomize the order of S_i each time it is compared to a V_n,m.

```
dat <-matrix(rnorm(30, 50, 20), ncol=5)
dat <-as.data.frame(round(dat))
s     <-matrix(rnorm(60, 7, 2), ncol=5)
s     <-as.data.frame(s)

findIndex <- function(c1,tv){
    index <- min(which(c1>=tv))
    index <- ifelse(index<Inf,index, 0)
    return(index)
}

processS <- function(s,v2){
# returns the first index of s[n] that has a cumsum >= 
# threshold hold value v2[n,m] or 0 if v2[n,m] > cumsum
    counts <- matrix(nrow = nrow(dat), ncol=ncol(dat))
    for (c in 1:ncol(dat)){
        for (r in 1:nrow(dat)){
            s_samp <- apply(s, 2, sample)
            counts[r,c] <- findIndex(cumsum(s_samp[,c]),dat[r,c])
        }
    }
    return(counts)
}

processS(s,dat)
```

Comment: This is great @ShawnMehan. Quick question/clarification. As I understand it, cumsum sums consecutive values starting at the top of S until the threshold is met, which means that all counts will be the cumsum of the same rows until the threshold is met, correct?. However, I want cumsum of random samples of S that meet the threshold. Does that make sense?. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ACBe, `sample` might be what you want, but you only want the count of how many of a given set of random elements are >= tv? It would be easier to `randomize` the order before if moves into the `findIndex(cumsum` it seems to me. I don't understand now what you're trying to achieve so I feel unable to advance on your problem at this point, tbh.

Comment: apologies for my lack of clarity. I edited the post above hoping to explain my problem better. Thanks again!

Comment: @ACBe, I think that this new formulation achieves what you're looking to do.

Comment: yes, I think this works!. Would you mind telling me what I was doing wrong with the while loop?. Thanks!

Comment: If it works for you, you could up vote the answer, please. The for loop seems more straightforward to me, since one needs to move through the entire rXc set of values in dat - this makes it explicit. Also, `cumsum` is doing some of the lifting for you. But I'm certain that it could be achieved with a while loop as well.